# Get list of installed profiles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, profiles

Is there any way to programmatically get list of installed Provisioning/Configuration profiles from iPhone (located in Settings/General/Profiles)?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Anything outside your application's sandbox is not accessible. You can't read/write other applications' sandbox(especially Apple's application). So it is not possible, if you are developing an application for app store.

Comment: Agree with view. But for example "Junos Pulse" application in app store can access to your profiles! You can try it by yourself. It's free.